# signedRequest doesn't return if user has liked the page

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Hello I am developing an fb app using facebook sdk (php version) but for some reason the signedRequest doesn't return me the liked variable in order to determine if the user has liked the page. Below is the print_r of signedrequest :

```
Array ( [id] => 395466473895310 [admin] => 1 )
```

any help appretiated

thanks
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> The 'liked' property will no longer be returned in the 'signed_request' object for Page Tab apps created after today. From November 5, 2014 onwards, the 'liked' property will always return 'true' regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.

Also, see the changes in the policy:

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a
>   Page. This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content
>   based on whether or not a person has liked a Page