# Facebook app detect page like - not working ok

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, detect

I use the clasic php facebook code for "like" detection. i put it on 2 fb apps. on one of the is working on one of them is not. in the one that is not working i can not receive the "like" key with 0 or 1 value that will tell me if the visitor has liked the page or not

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) 
{
    $app_secret = "...";
    $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], $app_secret);

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    print "</pre>";
} 

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) 
{
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') 
    {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) 
    {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }
    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) 
{
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
?>
```

in the one that is not working the $data array is like this

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 111111
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 111111
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => ro
            [locale] => en_GB
            [age] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )

        )

)
```

The "page" array must have also the "like" key but in this case is not there.

both apps have the same settings in the facebook developer section compared page by page more than 10 times.

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The like status does not get sent in new Apps anymore and like gating is not allowed after November 2014.

See this thread for further information: [signedRequest doesn't return if user has liked the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743990/signedrequest-doesnt-return-if-user-has-liked-the-page/25744705#25744705)

Answer (score 0):

If you created the app which isn't able to get the `liked` property recently or created it long ago but never used it, it's probably not receiving it because that property was deprecated in API versions `2.1` or higher - there's more about that change here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1

> The 'liked' property will no longer be returned in the 'signed_request' object for Page Tab apps created after today. From
>   November 5, 2014 onwards, the 'liked' property will always return
>   'true' regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.